# Use youtube api to get video list with swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, youtube-api

I would like to get back the title, id of the videos of a channel for but I block at the level of the JSON. It effect, when I try to make MYJSONARRAY ["items"] [0], nothing displays:/
Thank you for your help :)

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=**************Q&channelId=UCFNHx0ppCqm4EgPzEcOc29Q&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, reponse, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR")
        }else{
            if let content = data {
                do{
                    let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(myJsonArray["items"][0]) //NOT WORKING
                    //let test1 = myJsonArray["items"]
                    //print(myJsonArray)
                    print("\n \n --------------------- \n \n")
                    if let items = myJsonArray["items"] as? NSDictionary{
                        print(items) // NOT WORKING
                    }

                }catch{

                }
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

The answer of the api : https://pastebin.com/uWhmmJcm

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not casting correctly, AnyObject is not a suitable cast for a JSON response, It will usually be an array of dictionary items.

Change this line..

```
let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
```

to

```
if let myJsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any] {

//Now it's working

   if let items = myJsonArray["items"] as? [[String:Any]] {
       for item in items {
           print(item)
       }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but Xcode say "Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : Any]]' with an index of type 'String' " Thanks :)

Comment: Ok I change [[String:Any]] to [String:Any], now it's working thanks :)